# jquery's full calendar - removing all events for a single day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to remove all events for a single day using the jquery fullCalendar plugin. Is this possible?

I'm trying to do it via the removeEvents() function but i'm having no luck. The docs say I can pass in one Event Object argument but i'm not really sure what this means.

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', function(event) {
    if(event.start.toDateString()===new Date(2013, 1,1).toDateString())
        return true;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/wcR7a/

Basically, the `removeEvents` function goes through all your events and passes it to the second parameter. This parameter is a function above - which checks these events and returns true to all the events that have to be deleted.

Hope this helps!